# Problem on field extension related to irreducible polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

> Suppose $\gamma,\gamma'\in\Bbb C$ are distinct roots of the same irreducible polynomial $p\in\Bbb Q[x]$. Suppose $x^2-5$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Q(\gamma)[x] $. Show that it is also irreducible in $\Bbb Q(\gamma')[x] $.

My thought is that: $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 5)[x]$ is the field that $x^2-5$ is reducible, so if I can show that $\Bbb Q(\gamma')[x] $ is not a subfield of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 5)[x]$, or $\Bbb Q(\gamma')$ is not a subfield of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 5)$, then we are done.

Is this guess correct? If yes, what is the next step?

Thank you

Comment: I wouldn't say "the" field that $\;x^2-5\;$ is reducible, but **a** field in which that polynomial is reducible. And the polynomial *ring* $\;\Bbb Q(\gamma')[x]\;$ is **not** a field.

Comment: Some assumptions are missing in your question. I suppose that $p$ must be irreducible over $\mathbb Q$, otherwise we could take $\gamma=0,\gamma'=\sqrt{5}$, $p=x(x^2-5)$.

Comment: Your proposed argument isn't correct: $\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]5)\;$ is not a subfield of $\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt5)\;$ , yet $\;x^2-5\;$ is reducible in $\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]5)\;$ since $\;\sqrt5\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]5)\;$

Comment: Yes, Ewan is right, p should be irreducible over Q, I've edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose otherwise, then $\;x^2-5\;$ splits (there is no other option for a quadratic to be reducible) over $\;\Bbb Q(\gamma')\;$ , which means $\;\sqrt5\in\Bbb Q(\gamma')\;$ .

But we know there exists a $\;\Bbb Q\,-$ isomorphism $\;\phi:\Bbb Q(\gamma')\to\Bbb Q(\gamma)\;$ since $\;\gamma,\,\gamma'\;$ roots of the same irreducible polynomial $\;p(x)\in\Bbb Q[x]\;$ (without this assumption the claim is false, as the comments show), and then

$$\phi(\sqrt5)\in\Bbb Q(\gamma)\;,\;\;\text{and}\;\phi(\sqrt5)^2-5=\phi(5)-5=5-5=0\implies\phi(\sqrt5)$$

is a root of $\;x^2-5\;$ in $\;\Bbb Q(\gamma)\;$ , contradiction.